# How to identify user when using REST API

Tags: java, facebook, rest

Not sure the title is appropriate, but here is the problem 
1) I have REST API developed using Jersey (Java)
2) I want to use Facebook login to authenticate users
3) Now Once user has logged in to my website using FB, and API are beings accessed from my website using Ajax calls, how do I make sure requests are from already logged in user and also how to get the user identity(profile id etc.)

What would be best approach to address such API usage?

Comment: You could use Apache's Shiro. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076398/social-authentication-with-apache-shiro

Answer (score 0):

The user's 'profile' should be stored and accessed from the HttpSession.  Which your web container should manage for you and most likely will use cookies.  For example tomcat sets a cookie called jsessionid and uses that cookie for managing with session to use and therefore which user is making the request.

Generally for a 'REST' service, the end user should be validated every call.

I would recommend looking into [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (over ssl only) and/or [O-Auth2](http://oauth.net/2/).